# Trailing space in i to string conversion in ABAP

Tags: abap

On a SAP system, ABAP version 7.40 SP05, I just encountered a failure in unit tests on string comparison, but both strings should be the same?! Turns out it's not the case, as preceding conversion from i to string seems to produce extra trailing space in one of the strings.

This code bit:

```
DATA(i) = 111.
DATA(s1) = CONV string( i ).
DATA(s2) = '111'.
DATA(s3) = |111|.
```

Produces (as seen in debugger):

```
S1                                      111 3100310031002000    CString{4}
S2                                      111 310031003100    C(3)
S3                                      111 310031003100    CString{3}
```

The converted one has an extra trailing space. How does this happen and how can I prevent this to happen in i to string conversions? Obviously stuff like this makes me debug for a long time to find what is up (because unless I check the hex values, the debuger does not show that extra space...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand why the space is added in the first place, check the [documentation on the default conversion rules](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenconversion_type_ibs.htm) that are applied by `CONV`:

> The character "-" is set at the last position for a negative value,
>   and a blank is set for a positive value.

Since you can't use the [formatting options](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abapcompute_string_format_options.htm) of string expressions with the `CONV` operator, I'd suggest changing the code to use `|{ i }|` (which might be a good idea for other values as well, since you'll probably need some formatting options when comparing date / time values in unit tests anyway).

Comment: Thanks, I missed that in the docs and I was looking at the very same page today, pfff...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent it. The best way I found so far in ABAP is use `CONDENSE s1`

```
DATA i type i VALUE 12.
DATA idx TYPE string.
idx = i.       " idx = '12 '.
CONDENSE idx.  " idx = '12'.
```

Comment: I tend to avoid things like CONDENSE since introduction of more expression-oriented ABAP constructs. AFAIK there's no operand position equivalent of CONDENSE, like trim( ) function or so. The thing is I like to come up with lenghty and complicated FOR expressions and CONDENSE can't be part of those...

Comment: There is one now as of 7.50 (the format looks like `condense( val = ... )`: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abencondense_functions.htm